# MongoTemplate Sorting isn't working for LocalDateTime

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a SpringBoot app with Java 16 + GraphQL + Mongo.
I'm trying to find all the records by certains properties, which can happen to be NULL.
Also I'm trying to implement the Paging and Sorting, which as long as I used Mongo/JPA were working like a charm.
Then I had to step back and move to MongoTemplate in order to create a custom Criteria based on the populated properties passed. Now nothing is working properly.

My Document

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocaleDateTime createdAt;
}
```

My Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {

    Page<UserDocument> findUsersByProperties(String name, String email, Pageable page);
}
```

The class where I implement my Repo

```
    @Repository
    public class UserCustom implements UserRepository {
    
        @Autowired
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
        public Page<UserDocument> findUsersByProperties(String name, String email, Pageable page) {
            final Query query = new Query().with(page);
            final List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
    
            if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
                criteria.add(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
            }
            if (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) {
                criteria.add(Criteria.where("email").is(email));
            }
            
    
            List<UserDocument> users = mongoTemplate.find(query, UserDocument.class);
    
            return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(users, page,
                    () -> (long)users.size());
        }
   }
```

The code where I call this method and set Pageable

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(skip == 0 ? skip : skip/first, first).withSort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"createdAt"));
Page<UserDocument> result = userRepository.findUsersByProperties(name, email, pageable);
List<UserDocument> contentsResult = result.getContent();
```

What happens is that

1. the Sort isn't sorting: in the second Page, it returns many records from the first page. Is it a problem with the LocalDateTime? I looked it up and it really shouldn't. I tried to do

   query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"createdAt"));

but with the same result.

2. the pagination isn't complete, it always says the returned Page is the first and the last, hasNext() and hasPrevious() always return false but in the DB I have thousands of entries matching the criteria.
3. is there any chance to have a Slice as a return type with MongoTemplate? Without having to cast from List -> Page -> Slice

When debugging, the query object has skip, first and sort attributes correctly set, but then the result (at least of the sorting) is wrong. Still when I tell to skip 40 and take first 80, these logic seems to be correct.

I really don't know what I'm missing or if it's a kind of a limitation with MongoTemplate (which is new to me). Thank you in advance for any tip or ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest investigating [spring-boot-starter-data-search](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search).

- add the starter to your pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>app.commerce-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-search-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- enable the Search Repository:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = SearchRepositoryImpl.class)
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

- make your repository extends `SearchRepository``

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends SearchRepository<UserDocument, String> {
}
```

- use this repository to get your data

```java
String search = "name: myName and email: myEmail";
Page<UserDocument> result = userRepository.findAll(search, pageable);
```

You can find a demo for MongoDB [here](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search-mongodb-demo)

---

*Disclaimer: I'm a contributor of spring-boot-starter-data-search*